# Cannot make ionicModal template appear only one time upon entering a page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to use `ionicModal` to provide a instruction for the user only once(only the first time the user enter the page).

However for my current code, it appears every time the user goes into the page. I googled but did not see relevant results.

This is the working code(appears every time when user goes into page)

```
    .controller('formCtrl', function($scope,$ionicModal, getUrl,$state) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/instruction.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function(){
    $scope.modal.show();
  }
  $scope.closeModal = function(){
    $scope.modal.hide();
  }
  $scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
    $scope.openModal();
  });
})
```

Trying to modify it by putting in condition (does not work)

```
    .controller('formCtrl', function($scope,$ionicModal, getUrl,$state, getInstructions) {
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
    if(getInstructions.getInstruction() == true){

      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/instruction.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up',
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });

      $scope.openModal = function(){
        $scope.modal.show();
      }
      getInstructions.setInstruction(); //set as false

      $scope.closeModal = function() {
          $scope.modal.hide();
      };

      $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(scopes, states) {
        console.log("after enter");
        $scope.openModal();
      });
    }
  });
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    .controller('formCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, getUrl, $state, $rootScope) {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/instruction.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.openModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
    }
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    }
    $scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
        $rootScope.modelShown = true;
    });
    $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function(scopes, states) {
        if ($rootScope.modelShown != true) {
            $scope.openModal();
        }

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
.controller('formCtrl', function($scope,$ionicModal, getUrl,$state) {
   $scope.modalViewed = false;
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/instruction.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function(){
    $scope.modal.show();
  }
  $scope.closeModal = function(){
    $scope.modal.hide();
  }
  $scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
    if(!$scope.modalViewed){
      $scope.modalViewed = true;
      $scope.openModal();
    }  
  });
})
```

I have added a check variable to the scope `$scope.modalViewed`. And checking the condition before opening the modal.

This condition will not work if you remove the default caching of the ionic view. If its not cached the controller will run again and this code will not work. In that case you have to store the check variable `$scope.modalViewed` to your session storage, And remove initialising in the controller.